# SSH Tunnel + Socat UDP Forwarding + multiple clients

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, udp, socat

I have an Ubuntu machine running a server daemon (Unity3d unet game server in this case) that is designed to communicate with clients solely via UDP. The clients are on Windows 7 and Windows 10. Due to client network security requirements, I am required to make all connections via an SSH tunnel (which only transmits TCP packets). I can use Putty or cygwin OpenSSH on clients, but neither of these seem to support openssh's -w tunnel feature.

I have successfully configured `socat` to forward UDP packets via TCP between a single client and the server. On the server, following a slightly-modified version of [the instructions from the bottom of this page](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html). I am primarily a developer, and while I know enough unix networking to be dangerous, this is outside my typical skillset.

On the server I am running `$socat tcp4-listen:7776,reuseaddr,fork udp:localhost:7777`

On my client I am running `$socat -T15 udp-listen:7777,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:localhost:7776`.

I am then running a SSH tunnel from 7776 to localhost:7776.

This works well with a single client. However, as soon as I attempt to connect more than one client, both clients fail. My suspicion is that this is because `socat` is acting as a proxy, so my server sees multiple connections from localhost:7777 and neither the server nor socat has enough info to route the UDP packets back to their originators.

This smells like an ideal use case for virtual interfaces or dummy interfaces -- I believe if I could define virtual/dummy interfaces with unique IPs, eg: 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, etc, as virtual/dummies and bind an instance of `socat` to each virtual interface and have my clients set up their SSH tunnels with an endpoint of 10.0.0.*x*, I should be able to accept one client per interface. Obviously this doesn't scale, but I only need a few clients for this use case.

Am I thinking in a reasonable direction? If so, how do I route the dummies such that I can bind socat to them and have socat produce udp packets from 10.0.0.*x*:7777 routed to localhost:7777 (and accept packets from localhost:7777 to 10.0.0.*x*)?

I realize that there are better ways to achieve this (eg: a VPN, or ssf), but due to client requirements, I'm limited to solutions that run over a SSH tunnel. I can make a case to install additional software on the server, but all communication must to be via TCP over SSH tunnel.

[edit]It looks like one possible alternative would be to run openvpn on the server, then tunnel an openvpn client connection through the ssh tunnel. This seems messy but possibly more robust and extensible than futzing with socat. Any thoughts or opinions on these two potential solutions, given my requirements?[/edit]

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `ssh -w` - it does exactly that: build the tunnel and set up virtual interfaces on both ends.

`ssh -w x:y user@host network-script.sh` with network-script.sh setting up the server-sided interfaces will make it completly automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately my clients are on Windows, and neither putty nor any cygwin-based openssh build I can locate support -w. I'll edit my question to add this clarification.